# ¿Necesito Node.js en el servidor de producción?

Tags: nodejs, bootstrap, angularjs, reactjs, vuejs

A ver si podéis ayudarme. Os cuento, hace más de 10 años yo desarrollaba mis aplicaciones web utilizando ficheros html, php, css, js, etc... y luego lo subía a un servidor con apache y listo. El caso es que ahora me he sumergido en el mundo de vue.js y me han empezado a surgir algunas dudas. He estado buscando información pero hay muchos más tutoriales que otra cosa y todos van al grano, no he conseguido encontrar un lugar donde me lo aclaren bien.

Hice una app con Vue.js + bootstrap + node.js + Visual Studio Code. Para lanzar el servidor mientras desarrollo utilizo npm run serve, esto es un servidor Node si no me equivoco. Hasta ahí creo que no hay problemas.

Pero para hacer una build para producción uso el comando npm run build. Este último proceso me genera ficheros html, js y css. **No veo rastro de nada relacionado con Node.js ni de la estructura que utilizo en el desarrollo**. En este punto me puse a hacer pruebas con los archivos. Los puse en el servidor apache y no conseguía que se abriera la web en el navegador, al rato de hacer pruebas y reiniciar conseguí que funcionara. Eso fue lo que me hizo explotar la cabeza.

1. ¿No necesito Node.js en el servidor de producción? ¿Es que solo se
   usa en el desarrollo y al hacer la build se elimina la necesidad de
   usarlo en producción?
2. ¿Podéis facilitarme algún ejemplo sencillo donde intervenga Node.js,
   webpack y resuma groso modo el proceso desde el desarrollo a la
   producción, indicando que herramientas intervienen en cada fase?

He buscado bastante, pero os juro que ninguna web me aclara nada. Yo era feliz con notepad++, xampp, php, css, html, js, mysql, una clara separación entre cliente y servidor, un despliegue sencillo...

Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Bienvenido te recomiendo leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour], para conocer mejor como funciona la plataforma pues tu pregunta es muy amplia y por ende terminaría cerrada

Comment: Gracias @Aprendiz, lo he revisado todo y he aligerado un poco la pregunta. Solo necesito una respuesta muy conceptual que me ayude a poner en orden mis ideas.

Comment: Yo quitaría la segunda pregunta que haces, pues esa depende del nivel de conocimiento de cada usuario en la plataforma, por lo demás considero ya pudiera estar aceptable

Comment: Al leerte he pensado quitarla, pero @Ordago la ha respondido y creo que para quien llegue aquí con las mismas dudas y entienda mejor el contexto puede estar bien. Como digo Ordago ha dado en el clavo. Igualmente agradezco tus consejos. Un saludo!

Comment: Mientras hagas frontend, no necesitas nodejs en el serv. de producción, ya que sería solo necesario para compilar html y assets en general. Ahora, si usas backend, ahí podrías necesitar node dependiendo del framework que uses... o no (en caso que uses otro lenguaje en el backend)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ¿Estás seguro que tu aplicación es una aplicación de node.js (servidor) y no estás simplemente creando una aplicación web (javascript) usando el gestor de paquetes de npm?

Por lo que me parece (podría estar equivocado sin saber más detalles) estás usando npm para generar la aplicación y sus dependencias y webpack para el empaquetado de la aplicación.

Todo lo que te voy a responder es suponiendo que este fuera el caso:

Cuando haces `npm run serve` lo que se hace primero es cojer todo tu código fuente y empaquetarlo en un fichero js y un fichero css (aquí está interviniendo webpack, ver más abajo). Luego, se genera un fichero html que incluye esos dos ficheros, y por último se arranca un servidor node que te sirve el fichero html en localhost. Como ventaja de tenerlo así montado, es que si cambias algo de código fuente, el cambio se ejecuta en caliente y no tienes ni que dar a F5 para verlo. Cuando haces CTRL+C simplemente cierras el servidor node de desarrollo y no tienes que preocuparte más con el.

Cuando generas el código con `npm run build`, lo que estás generando son los mismos ficheros js, css y html pero en versión minimizada para ponerla en producción.

Si el fichero HTML que te genera te es útil, puedes usarlo, pero normalmente lo que haces es simplemente incluir el css y js en el código HTML de tu aplicación, ya que seguramente querrás configurar title, meta, etc.

Para ver un poco las tripas de lo que estás haciendo con npm puedes echarle un vistazo al fichero package.json, ya que allí puedes ver qué comandos estas ejecutando realmente.

Por ejemplo yo tengo algo así:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --port 8080 --hot --inline",
    "build": "env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "debug": "env NODE_ENV=development webpack"
  },
```

Esos son los comandos que se ejecutan cuando hago `npm run start`, `npm run build` y `npm run debug` respectivamente. Ese último me sirve para generar JS y CSS pero sin minimizar. El primero arranca el servidor de desarrollo en el puerto 8080.

Perdón de antemano si he dicho algo que no fuese totalmente preciso, yo también vengo de la vieja escuela y tampoco es que lleve mucho con esto, pero espero que te sirva de algo.

Comment: Pues si que me has aclarado mucho las cosas. Creo que tenía un error de concepto. Yo tengo un proyecto en Vue.js + un template basado en Bootstrap y recuerdo que en la descripción se especificaba que se requería Node.js. Por tu respuesta deduzco que Node.js solo se requiere durante el desarrollo porque, en mi caso, no estoy haciendo una aplicación de servidor.

Entonces ¿luego puedo publicar el resultado en un servidor web sin preocuparme más por Node?

Muchísimas grácias!

Comment: Estate atento por si alguien más te responde, que generalmente después de responder viene alguien y lo explica mil veces mejor, yo seguramente habré dicho alguna barbaridad xD

Comment: Pues iba a marcar tu respuesta como que resuelve mi duda. No creo que hayas dicho ninguna barbaridad, me cuadra muy bien. Pero te tomo la palabra. Esperaré un poco y si no veo una respuesta mejor en los próximos días la marco. De nuevo, muchas gracias!